# Listview onclick display options?

Tags: android

I currently have a listview which displays summarised data, i have an onlcick listener which works fine, but I was wondering what the best option would be to display all the data of the selected item?

I don't want to use toast, too small. Need a back button to return to the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I think I know what you're asking. Have you tried an `AlertDialog` or perhaps a custom class/`Activity` with the dialog theme?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the size of data, but here is a suggestion for you. Create a new Activity and set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` attribute of Activity in Manifest file. So the Activity will have a Dialog appereance like [this](http://www.google.com.tr/imgres?q=android+theme.dialog&hl=tr&sa=X&biw=1280&bih=607&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=nJuJ3Q2Fh8ueCM%3a&imgrefurl=http://sanirimbuyok.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-aktiviteler-aras-gecis.html&docid=vVjhRsmE_-1rdM&itg=1&w=491&h=334&ei=V5SDTojMKqag4gTotclw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=252&vpy=147&dur=2307&hovh=185&hovw=272&tx=118&ty=99&page=1&tbnh=106&tbnw=156&start=0&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0).